# Jest not close()ing expressjs server when run on AWS Codebuild

Tags: node.js, express, testing, jestjs, aws-codebuild

When I run locally jest exits fine, but when run on codebuild jest will not exit and gives this error:

> Jest has detected the following 1 open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting:
>
> ●  TCPSERVERWRAP

```
  13 | routes(app) 
  14 |  
> 15 | app.listen(port, async err => {
```

Both these variants work locally but not on codebuild:

```
  afterAll((done) => {
    if (app) {
      app.close(done);
    }
  })
```

```
  afterAll(async () => {
    if (app) {
      await app.close()      
    }
  })
```

Using `process.exit(0)` does not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, bit of an amateur error. When I wrapped the `app.close()` call it turned out that it was undefined. I was trying to run close on the express `request` object. I had to export the server object from where express was instantiated:

```
  afterAll(async () => {  
    try {
      await server.close()      
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
      throw error;
    }
  })
```

```
const app = express()
routes(app)

const server = app.listen(port, async err => {
  ...

module.exports = app
module.exports.server = server
```